# how to logout on blazor server side?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a problem with programming a logout in Blazor using `HttpContextAccessor`.

I tried to logout but it didn't do anything. What I want is just to delete some cookies in my browser and redirect to the hompage so I can and go to the login page again; I thought that by using the httpcontext signout I could automatically delete cookies because I'm logged out.

Here is the logout code:

```
      @page "/"
      @* @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime *@
      @* @inherits FragmentNavigationBase *@
      @using System.Security.Claims
      @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor
      @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
      @using System;
      @using System.Threading.Tasks;
      @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
      @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
      @inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage



      <Layout>
          <div class="container">
              <Bar
        Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Desktop"
        Background="Background.Light"
        ThemeContrast="ThemeContrast.Light"
      >
        <div>
          Booking Crew
        </div>
        <BarToggler />
        <BarMenu>
          <BarStart>
            <BarItem>
              <BarLink To="">Home</BarLink>
            </BarItem>
            <BarItem>
              <BarDropdown>
                <BarDropdownToggle>Report</BarDropdownToggle>
                <BarDropdownMenu>
                  <BarDropdownItem><BarLink To="report_crews">Report Crew</BarLink></BarDropdownItem>
                  <BarDropdownItem><BarLink To="report_studio">Report Studio</BarLink></BarDropdownItem>
                  <BarDropdownItem><BarLink To="report_schedule">Report Schedule</BarLink></BarDropdownItem>
                </BarDropdownMenu>
              </BarDropdown>
            </BarItem>
          </BarStart>
        </BarMenu>
        Hai, @EmployeeName  <span style="cursor: pointer;" @onclick="OnLogOut"> Logout</span>
      </Bar>
          </div>
        
      </Layout>

      @code{
        public string EmployeeName {get;set;}
          public string Email {get;set;}
          public string Nik {get;set;}
          public string NikLama {get;set;}
          protected override void OnInitialized()
          {
              var name = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
              name = name.ToString().ToLower();
              EmployeeName = name.Remove(1).ToUpper() + name.Substring(1);
              Email = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
              Nik = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:T7SSO:nik")?.Value;
              NikLama = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:T7SSO:nik_lama")?.Value;
              var test = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:T7SSO:nik")?.Value;;
              Console.WriteLine(test);
          }

          protected void OnLogOut()
          {
              _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(
                      CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
              NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
          }

      }
```

I thought using `signoutAsync` was enough to sign the user out but, when I click on logout, nothing is happening. How can I solve that?

Comment: Could it be, that SignOutAsync, signs you out `async`? So you navigate away, before the signout actually happens. You'd need to `await` it.

Comment: I put in an async await. and got these error `Unhandled exception rendering component: Headers are read-only, response has already started.`

Comment: what do you mean? i can't use httpcontext in signalR? so i cannot have signoutasync?

Comment: so basically u said that i cant use a signoutasync on http context? then how can i push logout for my blazor? i didn't use identity manager, what i need are just delete the cookies

Comment: i think it's not the same as this, bevause whern i tried to make it logout it didn't works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blazor Server uses SignalR, which means after `Startup.Configure` has run its course, [you can no longer safely access the `HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-and-shared-state), i.e. from your component.

> **Additionally, again for security reasons, you must not use IHttpContextAccessor within Blazor apps.** Blazor apps run outside of the context of the ASP.NET Core pipeline. The HttpContext isn't guaranteed to be available within the IHttpContextAccessor, nor is it guaranteed to be holding the context that started the Blazor app.

If you need to remove a cookie, navigate to a logout URL that can be handled by code where the `HttpContext` is valid, such as a Controller or Middleware.

If you just need simple logout functionality, use Middleware and to avoid adding calls to `AddControllers` and `MapControllers`. Here's an example using inline Middleware:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    // ...
    app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    //             ^^^^^^^ the HttpContext
        if (context.Request.Path
                .Equals("/Logout", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
        {
            // Remove cookie, redirect to landing, and any other logout logic
        }
        await next();
    });
    // ...
}
```

If you go this route, consider making a [custom middleware class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-5.0#middleware-class) instead.

Comment: Sorry Conner, I did expect by calling 

navigationManager.NavigateTo("/Logout");

I would run over my logout page, but is keeps telling me

Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

Comment: Hi, @Dinand, it sounds like you didn't create a Logout route (e.g. `@page "Logout"` in a razor component). Otherwise, you might want to open up a new question.

Comment: Hi @Connor, I was not able to work with your solution. It seems so simple, and it's an interesting option. I found some information about middleware functionality, and dive into it.  For now, I could solve it with JSRuntime, like it's shown in my answer. Anyway, Thank you for your answer, it may open some new possibilities.

Comment: Hi @Connor-Low. I studied and figured out my problem with your solution, and learned a lot about middleware which is pretty interesting.  Especially with Blazor. Thanks again for setting me on that path and for your solution.

Comment: So annoying when people say, "Thanks to you I found the answer!". . .  and then don't share the answer.